# Finding family of curves (ODE)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find the family of curves whose tangents form an angle $\pi/4$ with the hyperbolas $xy=c,c>0$

I know we need to find the DE of the the given family of hyperbolas, but what do we do after that ? Any clue is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let starting with $C:~xy=c,~~c>0$ which is a $1-$parameter family of curves. We have: $$y=\frac{c}{x},~x\neq 0\longrightarrow y'=\frac{-c}{x^2},~x\neq 0$$ This means that the slope of all tangents of above family of curves will be given by $$m_C=y'=\frac{-c}{x^2},~x\neq 0$$ Now if we assume that $y'$ be stood for the slopes of all tangent of desired $1-$family curves, regarding to our assumption, we have $$1=\tan(\pi/4)=\frac{m_C-y'}{1+m_Cy'}=\frac{\frac{-c}{x^2}-y'}{1+\frac{-c}{x^2}y'}$$ Or $y'=...$ and by solving this first order separable ODE we have $y=...$

[image]

Comment: Awesome plot! $\overset{\small ++}{\smile}$